# Passing/Editing Data Between react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to ask if i have 3 components which are not parent-son(please dont ask me join the 3buttons into one components) relationship as below , if i apply redux and put they under the same a store ,
is it possible to click the **Button1** through reducre to edit **input3** value 
(please assume all the Mapstatetoprops is done)

Thankyou

---

Button1

|

Button2

|

Button3

---

**Components**

```
class Button1 extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                 <Button id="Button1" ></Button>
                 <input id="input1" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Button2 extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                 <Button id="Button2" ></Button>
                  <input id="input2" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class Button3 extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                 <Button id="Button3" ></Button>
                 <input id="input3" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**ReactDOM**

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <Button1/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('div1')
);

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <Button2/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('div2')
);

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <Button3/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('div3')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, As long as they have the same store. Everything you pass at the redux will reflect on the other components. This is essential when splitting a huge app into mini apps so people who do enterprise complexity apps will be manage efficiently.

Take a look at this example I made from this simple fiddle from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hganz/gk9kaopr/) . This fiddle creates a simple todo app.

```
 ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={todoStore}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={todoStore}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container2')
);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={todoStore}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container3')
);
```

Once I made a todo in the other component, it will be reflected to the other two.
See the edited fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/gk9kaopr/2455/

So technically what you want to achieve is feasible and is way to go when splitting an huge monolithic app into different (react components) mini apps

PS: The original fiddle is not mine. Just edited it for the sake of a sample.

Comment: is it possible to use ref to access DOM in other components? i mean the relationship like those 3 buttons above